# Add dynamically added textbox value from User Control to main form

Tags: c#, winforms

In my main form I have a textbox namely `textBoxTotalTotal` and I want all the dynamically added textbox to be the added/sum in my `textBoxTotalTotal` How can I achieve that?
In my main form I have this:
`textBoxTotalTotal` 
Then in my User Control I have this

```
 public void textBoxTranspo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
  int intTranspo = 0, intBoxDaily = 0;
   if (int.TryParse(textBoxTranspo.Text, out intTranspo) && int.TryParse(textBoxDaily.Text, out intBoxDaily))
   textBoxTotalAmount.Text = (intTranspo + intBoxDaily).ToString();
    }
```

and

```
public void textBoxDaily_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
      int intTranspo = 0, intBoxDaily = 0;
       if (int.TryParse(textBoxTranspo.Text, out intTranspo) && int.TryParse(textBoxDaily.Text, out intBoxDaily))
       textBoxTotalAmount.Text = (intTranspo + intBoxDaily).ToString();
        }
```

Note that I am dynamically adding that User Control via button in the main form as many times I like. So the `textBoxTotalTotal` should just add them up wheter a new 2 textbox comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that UserControls' Parent is Form1 and User Control type MyUserControl:
(You should set the correct parent, and user control type)

```
MyUserControl[] controls = Form1.Controls.OfType<MyUserControl>().ToArray();
int Total = 0;
for(int i=0;i<controls.Length;i++){
    controls[i].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList()
    .ForEach(txt => Total += int.Parse(txt.Text));
}
```

If you are doing it from the UserControl itself then:

```
MyUserControl[] controls = Parent.Controls.OfType<MyUserControl>().ToArray();
int Total = 0;
for(int i=0;i<controls.Length;i++){
    controls[i].Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList()
    .ForEach(txt => Total += int.Parse(txt.Text));
}
```

Comment: Hello, how can I determine which is the parent of UserControl?

Comment: usercontrol.Parent ?